# What is correct color management setting for maximum dynamic range and flexibility?

Tags: filmic-blender

Today I decided to test all color management options in blender.
[Here is a comparison from left to right filmic log, raw, standard,filmic.jpg,filmic.exr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/197SkMF_ieE--GMi2Xv8AnG7GR7L9f-Ts/view?usp=drivesdk)

Any changes  I make in color management tab has no effect if I save render as exr.
So what is the correct workflow if I want to post process my renders and have enough dynamic range + data for the same purpose ? 
Thank you

Comment: @MrZak i tried to upload photo from my disk but got an error "something went wrong" .

Comment: For clarity, EXR is entirely designed for colour management, but the implementation of management in Blender is broken due to a ridiculous design decision.

Comment: @troy_s thanks for reply sir. I got my answer and now I just render to exr and grade in nuke. No problem at all. My only doubt is about the false color view. If I want to adjust my lighting to avoid over exposure I must change light intensity of lamps/hdris and not the exposure vlue of color management tab , am I right ?

Comment: In terms of “over-exposure”, there is only the range of data your camera rendering transform has; the scene light fits into the range given, both up and down. Exposure as a general “knob” to twist uniformly scales the data, where adjusting light intensity will change how the scene responds, including caustics, radiosity, subsurface scattering, etc. Don’t worry about exposure. Worry about making the image you wish, and let the camera rendering transform handle the roll off and gamut compression.

Comment: @troy_s Thank you sir